# how to know if a pointer is assigned dynamic memory via c malloc or cpp new?

Tags: c++, c

In my code different pointers were assigned dynamic memory via both c malloc method and cpp new, Now my problem is that I've all these pointers with me without knowing whether to free them or delete them It is a vast code and I don't have permissions to access and correct them.Also there are many variables so that I can't manually check and know whether they are freeable or deletable.
So, I want to know if there is any method so that I can programmatically free them and delete them as per their creation status.

Comment: Are you primarily using C or C++, or a mix of both?

Comment: No, there's no portable way to know (and I don't know about non-portable ways even for the implementations that I use often). You *may* provide your global `new` replacement to introduce an explicit tracking, but that would be ridiculous, just fix your code, it's not going to be complicated - just replace all `malloc` with an appropriate `new`. Still, what scares me more is that if you have this kind of problem most probably you (1) don't have clear documentation about what has to be allocated with what, so, for example, I fully expect to be parts where your code expects pointers to memory...

Comment: Run this via some tool (ex:duma) to detect the issues. That's probably the easiest way.

Comment: ... allocated on the heap which are fed globals or stack variables. Also, it means that you are performing manual memory management instead of using `unique_ptr` and the STL containers, which is pretty bad as well.

Comment: You can override `new` with a custom one and simply delegate allocation to `malloc`, likewise for `delete`. Then simply `delete` everything. btw I think most `new` implementation does this

Comment: Thanks for the replies Matteo Italia,Sourav Ghosh,and snoopy.It is very clear that the problem is because of mixing up both the c and cpp techniques of dynamic memory creation.So I'll try to correct it and make all of them to be made with new.Can you provide me any link to know more about unique_ptr..

Comment: There is some fancy new website named google... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: hahaha Thank you,Its my fault I should not have asked reference for such a small stuff.